# High level audio library for C++

Tags: c++, audio, cross-platform, media

I need to know, if there is any library that can handle this features:

1. Decode the main formats (Mp3, Wav, Ogg, etc..)
2. Handle sample rates, volume, duration, seek, etc...
3. With the library, features that allow you to create an equalizer
4. Handle the channels count (stereo, mono, etc..)
5. Detect audio devices (output and input) and choose in what device I want to stream
6. Get Information of the song, title, album, and the default sample rate of the song.

I'm tired of looking for a library that can do this 6 features. I don't know if you can help me with this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you looked into the OpenAL (Open Audio Library) features? I don't know the features OpenAL provides, but it sounds like it *could* be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does it really have to be all in one library? For decoding, ffmpeg comes to mind. For sample rates.. well there's libsamplerate, and for tags there's taglib. Also, for playback there's PortAudio

Comment: I know, I found libraries like sox, that used liblame, libmad, libogg etc, but they are giving me problems. I used portaudio before (see my older questions), used libsox, and all of them gived me problems.

Im using audiere and im trying ffmpeg right now, and they seem to be working correctly! I will keep testing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`FFmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org)**

I'm shocked no one recommended it before me. It is an open source library, capable of converting just any media file you throw at it.

Comment: FFMPEG is great for personal use, but the licensing issues surrounding it are numerous.  Depending on your country and specifics on what you are doing, simply using it can be illegal.

Comment: They say on their website: "FFmpeg is free software licensed under the LGPL or GPL depending on your choice of configuration options. If you use FFmpeg or its constituent libraries, you must adhere to the terms of the license in question. You can find basic compliance information and get licensing help on our license and legal considerations page.", refer to this [link](http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html) @Brad

Comment: I'm not talking about LGPL/GPL... that part is clear.  I'm talking about restrictions on patented codecs.  A quote from that page you link to, in response to commercial use:  "A: You might have a problem here. There have been cases where companies have used FFmpeg in their products. These companies found out that once you start trying to make money from patented technologies, the owners of the patents will come after their licensing fees. Notably, MPEG LA is vigilant and diligent about collecting for MPEG-related technologies."

Comment: Adding to the above, VLC uses it and as I've known, no one ever sued VLC for suing FFmpeg. @Brad

Comment: What would you sue?  VideoLAN is a non-profit org that has no money.  Just because a particular organization has never been sued doesn't mean you won't.  Consult a lawyer.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: The OP specifications suggest he just wants to decode formats, so I don't think it would be a trouble. If he wants to encode audio/video, he should've mentioned it. @Brad

Comment: Well, AFAIK, no one can sue you for decoding their format to WAV or RAW. @Brad

Comment: Sean, you're missing my point.  **I am not suggesting you don't use it.**  I am simply pointing out the problem of legal issues around FFMPEG and codecs it uses.  You are acting as if you have to defend your answer... you don't.  I am simply adding a very important piece of information that you left out.  And yes, you absolutely can be sued for usage of an improperly licensed encoder/decoder.

Comment: I'm not defending anything, I'm just trying to have a healthy discussion, please don't take it the wrong way, if you ever did. :P @Brad

Comment: I will try ffmpeg too, later. I will see which library it's better, ffmpeg or audiere, im worried about licensing too...

Comment: Well, as it's been said, Decoding from a format won't give you any trouble as long as you don't start using the library as an encoding tool. So you're good to use just anything that is open source. @Spamdark

Comment: Yep, Thanks so much! Ffmpeg its a really good option. Audiere too, I will see wich one its better testing them.

Comment: Well, I will use FFMpeg, do you have any tutorial about the library there? Thanks! ;)

Comment: Here's a reference: [how to use the library](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/111468/FFmpeg-Tutorial), if you don't understand anything, just ask. :) @Spamdark

Answer (score 1):

Check out BASS:  http://www.un4seen.com/

It can do the bulk of what you are wanting to do.  I think the only thing it doesn't do is getting metadata.

Comment: I know that OP didn't mention licencing / open source, but I want to add that BASS *isn't* open source, just if he needs it to be, or for future visitors.

Comment: @leemes, That's correct.  It is not open source.  It is free for non-commercial projects, and a commercial license is available.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of or looked into [Audiere](http://audiere.sourceforge.net/), or OpenAL ?

Comment: OpenAL seems kind of overkill, considering OP probably only wants replay (and no 3D audio stuff)

Comment: My thought processes when reading the scope of the question without knowing the scope of the project was it could potentially progress into 3D sound, or advanced stereo. So I opted for idea's that were best bang for buck library wise. Just a kind of "in the future should I want to expand to something, the library I'm using now will go with it" type thought.

Comment: +1 for open source and LGPL licencing ;) (both Audiere and OpenAL are LGPL)

Comment: Open Source is always the way to go, if nothing else seeing other people's coding can make you a better programmer. IMO.